# Save a series of images from a video?

Tags: export, video-sequence-editor, image

I'm doing a film where I'll be adding drawings on top of a film, so I need still frame of the film. I've found how to just save one image, but is there a way to say save an image/screenshot of a film every quarter second so that I have a series of images to work off of?  Did that make a lick of sense?

Thanks!

Edited to add: m.ardito solved it for me.  I'm doing the drawings in corel painter so I just needed images to use in there.  Thanks for all the help everyone. :)

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information. How are you adding your "drawings"? Are you using the grease pencil?

Comment: Basically you want to render only every x number of frames, correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others said, blender could help you in different ways, just better explain what you are after.

If you just really need to save images as described now, you could add the movie in the Vse then:

either render as animation to png sequence (you get all the frames, each as png), then select the ones you need

Or move at desired frames (every quarter second) and then save that single frame as png. This may be automated with a python script.

Comment: Thank you! The render as animation to png sequence was exactly what I needed.  You're the best! :)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `camera tracking` in Blender. [BlenderGuru](https://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/introduction-to-camera-tracking) and [BlenderNation](https://www.blendernation.com/2017/02/25/blender-camera-tracking-tutorial/) have tutorials on this. Note that this is different from `camera mapping`.

Yes, this does not answer the question posed directly above, but I believe it poses the motivation behind the question - how to create a 'drawing' that follows the film.